# weakSelf when setting frame

Tags: ios, objective-c, block

I recently read [this post](http://aceontech.com/objc/ios/2014/01/10/weakify-a-more-elegant-solution-to-weakself.html) and figured it would be a good idea to use the tips from the article. I'm using it in blocks, but should I also use it in the 'block' below. Is the 'block' below a real block?

```
avatar.frame = ({
    CGRect frame = avatar.frame;
    frame.origin.y = CGRectGetMaxY(self.view);
    frame;
});
```

That would become:

```
__weak typeof(self)weakSelf = self;
avatar.frame = ({
    __strong typeof(weakSelf)strongSelf = weakSelf;

    CGRect frame = avatar.frame;
    frame.origin.y = CGRectGetMaxY(strongSelf.view);
    frame;
});
```

Comment: No, it's not a real objc block. This is allowed by compiler extension. You don't have to weakly self.

Comment: @MaciejOczko Thanks, but I do have to do it in regular blocks, right?

Comment: @yoeriboven: That really depends on how the block is used. Is the block executed synchronously or asynchronously? It is stored in some collection for later execution or not? Do you *want* to keep a strong reference to self or not? There is no "one fits all" answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not a block. It is an GCC C extension, which causes a  *code block*
 to return a value if enclosed within brackets and parentheses.

> This not only segregates configuration details into initialization,
>   but the additional scope allows generic variable names like frame,
>   button, and view to be reused in subsequent initializations. No more
>   loginButtonFrame = ... / signupButtonFrame = ...!

source: http://nshipster.com/new-years-2014/

Answer (score 1):

This is not a block, block start with ^.
I believe this code:

```
({
    CGRect frame = avatar.frame;
    frame.origin.y = CGRectGetMaxY(self.view);
    frame;
});
```

Is a way to create a CGRect.

Comment: Not necessarily bad. It is a "compound statement expression" and allows you for example to use local variables in an expression.

Comment: @MartinR yes I checked this out and I amended my answer. Thanks